# Why does this yas-snippet (with yas-selected-text) not moving the cursor as intended?

Tags: latex, yasnippet

I have following yas-snippet for inserting latex equation parenthesis in selected region.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: parenthesis_region_()
# binding: M-r ( )
# --
\left(
    `yas-selected-text` 
\right)
$0
```

I use `evil-mode`.

1. When I mark a region with `v` (`evil-visual-char`), and run above snippet with `M-r ()`. Cursor ends up on `)` character (in `\right)`).
   [image]
2. When I mark a region with `V` (`evil-visual-line`), and run above snippet with `M-r ()`. Cursor ends up on `\` character (in `\left(`).

[image]

In both cases, cursor doesn't end up next line of `\right)`. The case 1 is acceptable for me (I can live with that). But the case 2 is vastly different and inconvenient.

**Question**:

- Why these 2 have different outcomes?
- How can I make them behave same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: parenthesis_region_()
# binding: M-r ( )
# --
\left(
    `yas-selected-text`
\right)
`(deactivate-mark)`$0
```

UPDATE:

I've noticed that `V` inserts a new line in the result, to remove it, you can use this for both.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: parenthesis_region_()
# binding: M-r ( )
# --
\left(
    `(replace-regexp-in-string "\n$" "" yas-selected-text)`
\right)
`(deactivate-mark)`$0
```

Mind you, you will lose the `gv` command to re-select the last selected region, but I suppose you wouldn't need it anyway.

To answer the whys: I think for `V`, the cursor jumps back to the beginning of the last selected region point, hence you can deactivate the mark. Not sure for `v`, but it would have worked if you just put a space before `$0`. It might be because the cursor steps back as you come out of the insert state. See `evil-move-cursor-back`, although, it might be down to the mark as well, or something else.

Comment: Thanks !!!, I didn't even know existence of `gv` command before. It's good learn Vim commands from Emacs site !.

Comment: Please see the update above.

Comment: Also, have a look at `cdlatex` package. You might be re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: Also, I am sure there are plenty of resources to learn Vim commands, but for me the "Practical Vim" by Drew Neil was the turning point.